# How to configure Mercurial to use Kompare when merging?

Tags: mercurial, merge, diff

I've tried adding `merge=kompare` to my `~/.hgrc`, but when I run `hg merge`, it runs kompare, but there's no UI to be seen. Hg says `merging path/to/first-file` and stays there, actionless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will also need to add a section that explains how to call Kompare. I don't know Kompare, so I don't know what the command line should look like (no guarantees for the `kompare.args` line), but it should be something like this:

```
[merge-tools]
kompare.executable = C:\<path...>\kompare.exe
kompare.args = $base $local $other -o $output
kompare.priority = 1
kompare.gui = True
kompare.binary = True
```

If merges aren't detected correctly, you might want to add

```
kompare.checkconflicts = True
kompare.checkchanged = True
```

Comment: kompare.args are completely wrong; those would work fine for kdiff3, but make no sense for kompare.  For instance, -o means ``This will open URL1 and expect it to be diff output.''  Obviously this is not the case.  On top of that, kompare doesn't do 3-way merges, so there's no point in giving it 3 files.

Comment: @scvalex: Thanks for the information. As I wrote, I don't know Kompare (and didn't look further into it when my answer was accepted). Of course, if it can't do 3-way merges anyway, it's not really a good idea to use it in Mercurial I guess. I would still like to correct my answer - can you help me out here?

Answer (score 4):

The `kompare.args` posted earlier probably wont work. I've had difficulty using Kompare for merging, especially 3-way merges (which are preferred and safe).
BTW, most of the other options are enabled by default I believe, but you can verify with: `hg showconfig merge-tools`

You are better off using kdiff3. Incase you are on Ubuntu Intrepid, kdiff3 was erroneously removed from the repos - but you can easily compile from source.

Comment: Yeah, I ended up going for kdiff3 too.

Comment: So how did you configure kdiff3 for mercurial?

Answer (score 0):

Kompare does not support 3-way diffs, so it can be used for Visual Diff feature only. Here's the config to make it work:

```
[merge-tools]
kompare.executable = kompare
kompare.diffargs = -c $parent $child
kompare.gui = True
```

Note the `diffargs` field instead of `args`.